# Doctrine and DateTime showing wrong difference

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I can't wrap my head around an issue with `DateTime()`. I want the difference between some saved time in the database and now. It works on my local machine but not on the live server.

This is my field definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $startTime;    
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $endTime;
```

Setting start and end time and then calcualting the difference always works:

```
$diff = $entry->getEndTime()->diff($entry->getStartTime());
```

**If only start time is set, I want the difference to the current time**, so I do this:

```
$diff = (new \DateTime())->diff($entry->getStartTime());
```

But this does not work. **The difference is 2 hours to low**.

Start and end time are set with an form input like that:

```
// user inputs for example: 08:50 for $start and 17:45 for $end
$dateStr = date('Y-m-d');
$entry->setStartTime(new \DateTime($dateStr.' '.$start));
$entry->setEndTime(new \DateTime($dateStr.' '.$end));
```

I am guessing the 2 hours off come from having the timezone Europe/Berlin instead of UTC, but **how do I accomodate for this?**

Replacing `new \DateTime()`
with `new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))`
or `new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))`
has no effect.

Thanks for you help.

**Edit as requested**

```
$currentDate = new \DateTime();
$currentDate->modify($currentDate->getOffset() . ' seconds');
// var_dump($entry->getStartTime())
object(DateTime)#358 (3) {
  ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-06-29 09:20:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
  ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC"
}
// var_dump($currentDate)
object(DateTime)#337 (3) {
  ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-06-29 06:50:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
  ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC"
}
// local time: 11:20:00
// difference should be: 2:30 but is 0:30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Berliner user fills 12:00 (12:00 Europe/Berlin in is mind - 10:00 in UTC time), doctrine saves a date (12:00) with no timezone.

When you retrieve you DateTime field, it is recreated by Doctrine as a 12:00 **UTC** (default application timeZone) and not a 12:00 **Berlin**.

So, you need to store User timezone in order to compare user provided dates with system provided ones. See [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#handling-different-timezones-with-the-datetime-type)

Answer (score 1):

As `DateTime::diff` compares two date-objects it doesn't matter whether you set it to any timezone or not, as it  - as far as I know - will first create the time and then set the timezone adapting the internal date appropriately. So `new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('Europe/Berlin'))` and `new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('UTC'))` reference the same time.

Therefore you will have to look what timezone your `$entry->getStartTime()` is in and adapt that appropriately to get the desired result. As the start (and end) time are given via a form I assume that you add them to the Entity **without** any timezone-information or with timezone UTC and you therefore compare a UTC-datetime with a Europe/Berlin-datetime. You should add those dates with a timezone-information to the database.

So as a workaround the following should work, but it is not a fix to the actual problem!

```
$currentDate = new \DateTime();
$currentDate->modify($currentDate->getOffset() . ' seconds');
$diff = $currentDate->diff($entry->getStartTime());
```

Comment: +1 for effort and the explanation, but it is not working for me.

Comment: can you post the result of var_dump($entry->getStartTime()) and var_dump($currentDate)?

Comment: Added it to my question, hope it helps.

Comment: what should be the diffeence between the dates? From what I read from the dates the difference is 2:34 h but I assume that it should be 0:34h. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh and I assume you have read http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html already.

Comment: It is the other way around, I've updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to missunderstand something... ```var_dump((new DateTime('2014-06-29 09:20:00+00:00', new DateTimezone('UTC')))->diff(new DateTime('2014-06-29 06:50:00', new DAteTimezone('UTC'))));"``` clearly states, that the difference is 2:30 Hours. What am I missing? Oh, and @david-jacquel answer solves the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

new \DateTime() returns your server time. And I guess your server is 2 hour late.

a **date** command in your terminal will tell you if I'm right.

Comment: It is, but what can I do about it. Changing the time zone of the system is not an option.